# Adding The data into another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

[Continuing from previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168167/how-to-get-the-last-updated-item-in-google-sheets)

This code recodes the last edited data from **Spreadsheet A Sheet1** into the same **Spreadsheet A **Sheet2****, but I want that data (**Spreadsheet A Sheet1**) to be added into another **Spreadsheet B Sheet2**

I couldn't configure how to modify the code since it looks a little complex to me.

Can you please help me to modify this code?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || range.rowStart == 1) return;
  const col = range.columnStart - 1;
  const [header, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const value = values[range.rowStart - 2];
  const v = [[`${value[0]} - ${value[1]}`, `${header[col]} - ${value[col]}`]];
  e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A2:B2").setValues(v);
  
}
```

Comment: You need to get the id of the other spreadsheet and then SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but I'm not sure where to add that code. it keeps giving error message.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A2:B2").setValues(v);
```

#### To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById("###SpreadsheetID of SpreadsheetB###").getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A2:B2").setValues(v);
```

And also, please rename the function name from `onEdit` to others like `installedOnEdit`. And, [please install OnEdit trigger to the renamed function as the installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). Because `openById` cannot be used with the simple trigger. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue of `it keeps giving error message`.

When you use this script, please edit the cell. By this, the script is run.

#### Note:

- When you install the OnEdit trigger to `onEdit` function when the cell is edited, both the simple trigger and the installable trigger are run with the asynchronous process. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5) So I proposed to rename the function name. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)