# How to make onEdit() only restricted to edition in specific range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to make onEdit function only respond to the specific range.
my onEdit function as bellow:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  if (//trigger only when the cells from column A:H is edited 
    sheetName == "Email list" &&
    range.rowStart >= 2 &&
    range.columnStart >= 1 &&
    range.columnStart <= 8
  ) {
    sendMail()
  }
}


function sendMail() {.... //the main function here
```

I have also deployed installable trigger using function onEdit. But I got **TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined**. Not sure which part is wrong or how should I define the variable within onEdit? Thank you.

Comment: The `onEdit` trigger is supposed to run automatically when the spreadsheet is edited. If you try to run it directly from the script editor you will get this error, because `e` is undefined. So, how is this function getting executed?

Answer (score 1):

Try following sample script:-

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  const range = e.range
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const column = range.getColumn();
  if (//trigger only when the cells from column A:H is edited 
    sheet.getName() == "Email list" &&
    row >= 2 && 
    column <= 8 // not taking 1 into consideration
  ) {
    sendMail()
  }
}
```

If you run the function directly, it will throw an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`, remove `Edit` installable trigger, as `onEdit()` is `simple trigger`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think this script works well. As I would like to have the function trigger automatically, should I just keep the installable trigger so that it can work by itself? After I remove the installable trigger, I could no longer have the the function work when editing in the reange.

Comment: You can use Installable trigger that will work the same, only difference is simple trigger works with rights of user trigger the event at that point of time, where else installable trigger works on the rights of user who installed it., so i guess Installable trigger is fine for  you. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to run your `onEdit` by not only OnEdit simple trigger but also the standalone without the simple trigger.
  In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit() { // If you want to use this function as the installable trigger, please rename the function name.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  if (//trigger only when the cells from column A:H is edited 
    sheetName == "Email list" &&
    range.rowStart >= 2 &&
    range.columnStart >= 1 &&
    range.columnStart <= 8
  ) {
    sendMail()
  }
}
```

- By this modification, you can directly run `onEdit`. And also, you can run `onEdit` by OnEdit trigger.

#### Note:

- When you want to use your `onEdit` using the installable trigger, please rename the function name. About this, I thought that this thread might be useful.

  - [Adding The data into another spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71215657/7108653)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Thank you so much for the input! Just to make sure I totally understand. With this logic, I create the function onEdit() in order to restrict the edit range; and I use installable trigger to trigger the main function when detecting any edit in the restricted range. Am I right? Will this mechanism be too redundant?

Comment: @Duh If your `sendMail()` includes the methods for sending email, please rename `onEdit` to other name. And please install OnEdit trigger. By this, you can run it using the installed OnEdit trigger. And, you can also run it with the script editor. When you use the installable OnEdit trigger, this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71215999/7108653

Comment: Thank you for providing the reference, just changed the name from onEdit to TriggeronEdit. However, the script above doesn't work even I have set up install trigger to trigger TriggeronEdit. When I check the log, the execution is actually completed with no error. Do you know why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: @Duh Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `However, the script above doesn't work even I have set up install trigger to trigger TriggeronEdit. When I check the log, the execution is actually completed with no error.`, in this case, your if statement might be `false`. If the if statement is `true`, `sendMail()` is run. How about this? But unfortunately, I cannot know the detailed method for correctly replicating your issue. So this is just my guess. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Not inconvenient at all. Don't apologize. Thank you for your support! I realized all I need is to trigger the sendEmail function when a new row is added via built-in functions, such as importrange and query. Therefore, either onEdit or onChange can't resolve this problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @Duh Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I realized all I need is to trigger the sendEmail function when a new row is added via built-in functions, such as importrange and query. Therefore, either onEdit or onChange can't resolve this problem, unfortunately.`, I cannot understand your current situation. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the detailed information? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. For instance, I have two sheets, Sheet A and Sheet B respectively. The responses from google form will be sent to Sheet A, and I use google sheet function "=query('Sheet A!)" to export the data with certain conditions to Sheet B. Under this circumstance, we could expect that every time a google form is submitted, a new row will be added in Sheet B ""without any manual edit"". In this case I assume onEdit would not be triggered as there's no detection of manual edit. 
I was just being a bit frustrated after knowing this fact as mentioned above.

Comment: @Duh Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that when OnSubmit trigger is used, your goal might be achieved. In your situation, when Google Form is submitted and the value is put to "Sheet A", using OnSubmit trigger, a script is run. How about this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I believe your suggestion would be very helpful in most of the cases. However, the data in my spreadsheet will be manipulated by other external application, which causes a delay on the process of query function. Simply speaking, there's a time lag (within an hour) between submission of google form and pushing data to 'Sheet A', and OnSubmit trigger would not function at the moment the data is push to 'Sheet A'

Comment: @Duh Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Simply speaking, there's a time lag (within an hour) between submission of google form and pushing data to 'Sheet A', and OnSubmit trigger would not function at the moment the data is push to 'Sheet A'`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. What I was trying to say is a description of my worksheet. After the the data pushed to 'Sheet A' through submission of google form, the data in 'sheet A' will be run by an external application. If there's an error with this execution, a false message is returned and the row is sent to 'Sheet B'. Since the procedure above takes about average 20 mins to be finished, I think OnSubmit can not be triggered at the right time to run the new row in 'Sheet B'.

Comment: @Duh Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your reply, in that case, when the OnSubmit trigger is run, how about installing the time-drive trigger for executing the script after 20 minutes? By this, your goal might be able to be achieved. If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your input! This idea sounds feasible, and I may give it a try. Will ask for additional help from experts here if needed. Thank you so much Tanaike.